# Buddypress Adding a Nav item and Calling Custom Fields

Tags: buddypress

```
function my_bp_nav_adder() 
{ 
bp_core_new_nav_item( 
array( 
    'name' => __('information', 'buddypress'), 
    'slug' => 'info', 
    'position' => 15, 
    'show_for_displayed_user' => true, 
    'screen_function' => 'all_conversations_link', 
    'default_subnav_slug' => 'testing', 
    'item_css_id' => 'all-conversations' 
)); 
} 
// Load a page template for your custom item. You'll need to have an item-one-   template.php and item-two-template.php in your theme root.
function all_conversations_link () {

}

add_action( 'bp_setup_nav', 'my_bp_nav_adder' );
```

I am trying to display some value of custom fields in the tab that I have just created called information.
I have created custom profile fields called location. using this code I am fetching the value

```
<?php

//code inside the directory loop

$location= xprofile_get_field_data( "Contact Person" ,bp_get_member_user_id());//fetch  the text for location
echo " $location ";

?>
```

However I get this to be a broken page.I do get the output but it is displayed at the top of the page.How to correctly format these values to fit in line and diplay like the profile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're not specifying which template BuddyPress should use to display your content. There are a couple of ways to do it (see https://github.com/boonebgorges/buddypress-skeleton-component/blob/master/includes/bp-example-screens.php for a few options), but I suggest the following

```
// This is the screen_function called in bp_core_new_nav_item()
function all_conversations_link() {
    add_action( 'bp_template_content', 'all_conversations_content' );
    bp_core_load_template( 'members/single/plugins' );
}

// This is the function that actually contains your content
function all_conversations_content() {
    $location= xprofile_get_field_data( "Contact Person" , bp_get_member_user_id());//fetch  the text for location
    echo " $location ";
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Solved . I hope I accepted your answer and thats all that needs to be done